# In Django, is on_delete implemented in Python, or using DB triggers, for PostgreSQL databases?

Tags: django, postgresql, foreign-keys

I have an application that shares a database between a large Django application, and a set of microservers (written in Go). If a record is deleted by a microserver, such that a record in a different table has a foreign key that references it, and if I've specified `on_delete=models.CASCADE` in the respective `ForeignKey` field, which of the following is true?

1. The dependent record will be deleted by PostgreSQL, or
2. the dependent record should be deleted "manually" by the microserver (this is what I currently do),

or is there a way to specify how I want `on_delete` to be handled?

Here's a bit of an example for completeness:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        Parent,
        null=False,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and in Go:

```
_, err = db.Exec(`DELETE FROM module_parent WHERE ID = $1`, parentID)
```

or do I have to do:

```
_, err = db.EXEC(`DELETE FROM module_child WHERE parent_id = $1`, parentID)

...

_ err = db.EXEC(`DELETE FROM module_parent WHERE id = $1`, parentID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd is true, per the [Django docs for ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete):

> `on_delete` doesn’t create a SQL constraint in the database. Support for database-level cascade options [may be implemented later](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21961).